# React Native :How to make changes in app without updating it again by the user?

Tags: react-native, updates, hot-reload

Is it possible to make a change in the user side (UI as well as funstionality) without updating the app again by the user? If yes , then what kind of architecture should follow when starting a new project? Could you please help me to know how is it possible?

Comment: You could consider use pwa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [CodePush](https://medium.com/@rajanmaharjan/get-started-with-wonderful-technology-d838aafdc2d3) through this you can push new changes directly to them as a user don't need to update the app.